# Serial not auto-incrementing when insert table into another table

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

When I insert a table (station) into another table (postes), the auto-incrementing serial "id_hta" is lost.

INSERT INTO station (code_hta, geom_hta)
SELECT code, geom FROM postes;

So, I tried :

```
INSERT INTO station (id_hta, code_hta, geom_hta) 
    VALUES(DEFAULT, (SELECT code_gto, geom FROM postes));
```

But I receive an error: The query must return a single column.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `values` clause when the source is a `SELECT` statement. And you can't use the `DEFAULT` clause inside a SELECT. So the solution is to not specify the column that is auto-generated:

```
INSERT INTO station (code_hta, geom_hta) 
SELECT code_gto, geom 
FROM postes
```

Comment: When I use this code, I lose the auto-incrementing of id_hta. All the added rows will not follow the initial increment.

Comment: If `id_hta` is defined as an `identity` (or the outdated `serial`) column, then this **will** increment the values for the new rows. If it doesn't then `id_hta` has no sequence associated with it.

Comment: @ennine: see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1723f6759fa46d52fcbd231572cc83d6

Comment: Many thanks. It works perfectly